# No Lights at Final Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

When I try to render my scene, there are no Lights at Final Render.

[image]

But if I use Shift+Z shortcut to see a preview, all works fine.

[image]

I really don't understand what is going on... Can you guys help this newbie? I installed Filmic Renderer that BlenderGuru recommended. Other than that, everyting are default, I think.

[image]

Comment: Are the lights in a layer that is not part of the render layer?

Comment: They are in the same layer. I mean interior lights are. The one behind the windows are in 3rd layer.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings. Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: I did that, lets wait..

Comment: Odd, the lights don't show up in the preview/viewport render for me. That said, the reason the lights aren't showing up in the final render is because layer 3 (the layer with the lights) is not enabled in the renderlayer (as cegaton suggested)

Comment: But here, all  the same layer.

Comment: But here, all is in the same layer. Preview can show the lights too. Very annoyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lights are not in the same layer.

They are in a layer that is not set to be rendered.

[image]

Once you enable the layer that holds the lights along with the one that holds the rest of the scene you will have lights...

[image]

Rendered image with both layers enabled

[image]

Alternatively you can set the lights to be active in more than one layer.

[image]